# JAVA8, parsing text file and parsing its values to objects

Tags: java, file, object, text, mapping

I have specific text file looking like this:

```
name: meeting_name1
description: 
04/18/2012 00:00:00
05/18/2012 00:00:00
... (more dates)
07/18/2012 00:00:00
name: meeting_name2
description: some_desc
04/18/2012 00:00:00
05/18/2012 00:00:00
... (more dates)
07/18/2012 00:00:00
(etc)
```

I have java object looking like this:

```
class Meeting {
    String name;
    String description;
    List<Date> dates;
}
```

My point is to read the file, parse values, create objects and save them to database.

I can read the file line by line and convert it to `List<String>`, ie. all data together. 
`I can make and fill one java object with values and save it to database.

**My issue here is how to find out that I'm at the end of dates and lines (name: meeting_name2) of new object begin.**

**So I could make something like `List<List<String>>` where `List<String>` would be equal to one object, ie. `List<Meeting>`?**

Not sure if its understandable, sorry for formatting.

Comment: Based on the sample input, name and description are identifiable with their key:value format so if the line does not represent a name and the line does not represent a description, then it's safe to assume the line represents a date.  Also, if you can, use `LocalDate` instead of `Date`.

Comment: This is not really clear. Maybe you could add some code to show what you have done so far and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: If name always comes before description, then a new `Meeting` instance would be needed whenever a line which represents a name is encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption that you could read the file data to List variable. (See above answer)

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("FILE_NAME"));
```

Now, you can see below code as a demo. It is the simple loop and if else statament.
Hope it will help you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add("name: meeting_name1");
        data.add("description: some_desc");
        data.add("07/18/2012 00:00:00");
        data.add("07/18/2012 00:00:00");
        data.add("name: meeting_name2");
        data.add("description: some_desc");
        data.add("07/18/2012 00:00:00");

        List<Meeting> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Meeting temp = null;
        for (String line : data) {
            if (line.startsWith("name:")) {
                temp = new Meeting(line.split(":")[1].trim());
                result.add(temp);
            } else if (line.startsWith("description:")) {
                temp.setDescription(line.split(":")[1].trim());
            } else {
                temp.getDates().add(simpleDateFormat.parse(line)); // Use date for
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result.get(0).getName() + ": " + result.get(0).getDates().size()); // meeting_name1: 2
        System.out.println(result.get(1).getName() + ": " + result.get(1).getDates().size()); // meeting_name2: 1    
    }

    static class Meeting {
        String name;
        String description;
        List<Date> dates;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public List<Date> getDates() {
            return dates;
        }

        Meeting(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            this.dates = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(f))                                                   {  List<String> ls = stream.sequential().collect(Collectors.toList());                   ls.forEach( c-> System.out.println(c)); }`

Comment: 1) `readAllLines` - is a java 7 way to read whole contents of a file to memory, since it reads the complete file, it may fail if the file is too large because it can not fit into memory.                                                                                              2) `lines` - is a java 8 way to read contents of a file, and it is different from readAllLines in 2 ways: a) it returns a Stream<String> object, b) the output (stream) is lazily populated, meaning, it won't read file upfront. It reads file as you consume the elements of the stream.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to read all lines first. You would not need to worry about the end of lines with:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("FILE_NAME"));
```

then iterarate through the array,
if a line starts with "name:" you make a new object and add the data like that:

```
        List<Meeting> meetings = new ArrayList();
        Meeting currentMeeting;

        for (String line : lines) {
            if(line.startsWith("name:"))
            {
                currentMeeting = new Meeting();
                meetings.add(currentMeeting);
                //...add data (name)
            }
            //...add more data (description and dates)
        }
```